# Connect a Microsoft Access database to another Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access 2013 database which has linked tables to a Microsoft Sql Server(Server1).

I need to change the connection from Server1 to Server2.
How can I do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I only have 2010, but it should be similar.
On the ribbon, go to **External Data**, then **Linked Table Manager**. This will give you a list of all your linked tables. **Select All**, and at the bottom, ***check the box*** that says "**Always prompt for new location**" and click **OK**.
It will then ask you to select the new location. It will do this once per current connection string. In your case, just once as you have everything pointing to just one server.
It will then relink all your tables to your new server. This takes about 30 seconds once you know what your doing.

Comment: Million thanks. 
I was looking for a Convert Main Data Source button as explained [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/infopath-help/change-the-sql-server-database-used-in-your-form-template-s-main-data-connection-HP010093127.aspx) or a Data Connection Button as explained [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/infopath-help/change-or-remove-a-data-connection-HP010095056.aspx?CTT=3)